# NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CompilerFactory] Angular

Tags: angular, jenkins, build, angular9

I have problem with my application. Angular 9.0.5
When i build (ng build --prod) application by Jenkins build pass but artifacts (runned by ie. http-server) are broken.

Show me error:

```
Uncaught NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CompilerFactory]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for CompilerFactory!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4201/vendor.js:17724:27)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4201/vendor.js:32313:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4201/vendor.js:32239:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4201/vendor.js:32080:20)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ (http://localhost:4201/vendor.js:53780:38)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:4201/vendor.js:54124:16)
    at Module../src/main.ts (http://localhost:4201/main.js:729:77)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:4201/runtime.js:85:30)
    at Object.0 (http://localhost:4201/main.js:741:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:4201/runtime.js:85:30)
```

But if i go to **THE SAME** location on my build machine and do ng build --prod then artifacts are working. This is kind of magic for me. Can anyone help me?

Comment: you have a main-aot.ts?

Comment: No i build with normal main.ts:
```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
  console.log('I AM IN PROD!!');
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

But other applications are builded on the same node with (i think so) the same setup and it works.

Comment: using angular 9?

Comment: sure, your Jenkins prod build isn't replacing your main.ts in any way?

Comment: i dont think so.

Yes angular 9.0.5.

I run ng build AFTER build by jenkins and it works.

Comment: **Have anyone idea how to get more detailed error?** This could help me.

Answer (score 2):

Ok i resolve issue.

In my case i was used `pnpm` as package manager.
And as dependecy i have non compiled packages (typescript)

And jenkins have problem with access to that long path ( pnpm use store to solve dependencies)

When i go to this machine on build workspace ( without cleaning) and run `ng build --prod`
then build was builded correctly artifacts.

**SOLUTION 1:** Use `npm` instead of `pnpm`
**SOLUTION 2:** Not using non-compiled packages (typescript)

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue but with Azure. How did you figure out that this was the problem?